# Movng data in Excel from one column to another without copy/cut & paste

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet for purchase orders that have been placed over a period of time. Depending upon the nature of the order, there are two columns for the vendor the material was ordered from. One is the Fixed Vendor column & the other is the Desired Vendor column. As such, if the order was placed using the desired vendor, the vendor number will appear in that column, but not in the fixed vendor column. When I download the spreadsheet, I need a way to combine the two columns so that the vendor numbers show in just one column. Is there a quick way to do this? I've tried cutting & pasting, but as there can be hundreds of lines per ss, this can be very time-consuming.

Comment: Why not add a pseudo column using formula and get the actual vendor used, can come from either of the column which is non empty?

Comment: @Myers24 - can you provide more detail such as: where are the Vendor names obtained; are the vendor names or numbers the relevant information; do you need to combine the two values (Desired and Fixed) into one column; are there other relevant data columns on the sheet?  If it's just combining two values, use the `CONCATENATE` function.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have at least two columns that matter. In my example I'll name them:
A (fixed)
B (desired)
C (combined column). You may need to create this column.

put this in c2: `=IF(A2<>"";A17;B17)`

Please add example of your sheet in an image if this is not what you are looking for.